# How do I restore access to local Django site using "python manage.py runserver" after upgrading Homebrew?

Tags: django, homebrew

I upgraded Homebrew in the terminal. After entering my virtual environment with no problem, I typed "python manage.py runserver" as usual, but I got the following error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I assume the upgrade requires me to change something, but I'm not sure what I need to do. Do I need to reinstall Django?

Comment: Are you sure that file manage.py exists at the path where you run the command?

Comment: It has always been there so I'm not sure why it would move or where it would move to.

Comment: you're definitely not running your command `python manage.py runserver` from inside the directory where `manage.py` is located, that's the only way this error can happen.

Comment: Ok, thank you to you both.